# How to get the current length of different arrays in jagged arrays using for-loops in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[][] array = {new char[] {'2','A','3','E'},
                          new char[] {'F','A'},
                          new char[] {'F','F','F','F'},
                          new char[] {'5','A','0','E','9'}};
        List<double> arr = new List<double>();
        List<double> results = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            double result = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < **array.Length**; index++)
            {
                char c = array[i][index];
                if (c > 47 && c < 58)
                {
                    arr.Add(c - 48);
                }
                else 
                {
                    arr.Add((c - 65)+10);
                }
            }
            int power = arr.Count();
            for (int ind = 0; ind < power; ind++)
            {
                arr[ind] = Math.Pow(16, power - 1) * arr[ind];
                power--;
                result += arr[ind];
            }
            arr = new List<double>();
            results.Add(result);
        }

    }
```

My goal is to convert these HEX numeric system numbers to Decimal numeric system numbers.
I know the easy and short way using Console.WriteLine()methods and Standard Numeric Format Strings, but the point is to do this hard way(using jagged arrays). All code work properly , but i dont know how to do change(or get current) value length of different inner arrays in jagged array. If i do it this way usign array.Length - it stay static and doesnt change like i need. I try to use array.GetLength(i) but it dosent work 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    ...
    for (int index = 0; index < **array.Length**; index++)
```

To get the required length, try

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    ...
    for (int index = 0; index < array[i].Length**; index++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the length of the **outer** array (`array.Length`), while you meant to read the size of the second, **inner** array (`array[i].Length`). Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array[i].Length; index++)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer for each

```
        var array = new[]{new[] {'2','A','3','E'},
                      new[] {'F','A'},
                      new[] {'F','F','F','F'},
                      new[] {'5','A','0','E','9'}};
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Length);
        }
```